# Adding a level counter that isn't linked to buildindex unity and randomising levels

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, counter, scene

I'm trying to add a Level counter to my game that isn't based on buildindex but haven't been able to find a way to do it so far. That leads to my next question, I need the counter to work inpendantly of buildindex because I want the levels to be played in a random order (with replaying the same level possible). So far to randomise levels I've come up with this:

```
private void NextLevel()
{
  SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManger.buildIndex + range(0,x)); //x would be the number of scenes
}
```

I haven't finished enough scenes to be able to test this yet to know if it works, if anyone knows a better way or would be able to confirm is this works or I should try come up with something else I would love to know!

Thank you for your time and any advice

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene-buildIndex.html has an example. Yours will not work unless you always want to choose a higher numbered scene. Shouldn't be that hard to add several more scenes to your game and test it.

Comment: To add to @RetiredNinja's point, you would only need to copy the scene and add something like a TextField that is different to each scene. You would be able to quickly test this.

Comment: Thats true ill add a couple dumby scenes later on when I can and test it. Any ideas for the level counter? I want it to be able to track completed levels

Answer (score 1):

You can get the full amount of available scenes via [`SceneManager.sceneCountInBuildSettings`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneCountInBuildSettings.html) and use that as the max value like

```
private void NextLevel()
{
     SceneManager.LoadScene(Random.Range(0,SceneManager.sceneCountInBuildSettings));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want scenes randomly you can use this :

```
private void RandomeLevel()
{
  //UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, Max)
  //Start 0 and End 4 = ("Max")
  int nextSceneIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 4);
  SceneManager.LoadScene(nextSceneIndex, LoadSceneMode.Single);
}
```